# How do I use oAuth with Google C# .NET APIs?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to use the .NET APIs from Google
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Authentication/

As most of these APIs from Google require an oAuth token for you to fetch any data from them, I am struggling to get over this first hurdle.

My plan is to create a very simple .NET Web API that lists out my Google Analytic's accounts via the API which I can then in turn use with AngularJS to bind to a nice little view with the JSON returned from my WebAPI call.

The problem I mentioned is that there seems to be lots of different  examples floating about and I can't seem to get any to to work. Either its out of date or the sample project doesn't compile etc...

From what I can understand I need to pass an Authenticator object to the BaseClient object which is in turn used for any Service API.

Below is a rough example I am trying to get to work, but currently fails and gets an error back from Google's API because I am not logged in/passing an oAuth token. Can anyone give me any pointers or advice please.

Thanks, Warren

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Account> GetAccounts()
{
    var baseClient              = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
    baseClient.ApplicationName  = "Google Stats Example";
    baseClient.Authenticator    = null; //Unsure how to get the oAuth token

    AnalyticsService stats      = new AnalyticsService(baseClient);
    var accounts                = stats.Management.Accounts.List();
    var allAccounts             = accounts.Execute();

    return allAccounts.Items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an authenticator you need a nuget package named "Google APIs OAuth2 Client Library" but i downloaded a nugget package named "Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2 Client Library". Similar names but not the same.

I was not able to find the correct one on nugget page. If you perform a search on that package it wont show up. I had to use Visual Studio Nugget searcher and activate "show prerealese packages" to install it.

Comment: Thanks I think I have the same nugget installed and need to try the other one you are suggesting. Do you have a working example please that I can take a look at please?

Comment: Once that you install the right package you can use any example. Like this one:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.SimpleOAuth2/Program.cs?repo=samples

Comment: Thanks I have tried the ASP.NET WebForms example from that repo and it works fantastic.


I just need to try and figure out how this would work in a ASP.NET WebAPI context.

Comment: What I want to do is to use the Google YouTube Analytics's API but for my own YouTube channel, hence I don't want users visiting the site to authenticate the API call using their own details.

So the goal is to get some kind of permanent oAuth key or access token so I can do API calls to fetch my channel's YouTube statistics. Is this possible and if so how should I be going about it?

Comment: You can use authentication server type instead of user authentication. You can get a private key on your google console:

var provider = new Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.AssertionFlowClient(Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)

Comment: Then you can suthenticate your site like this:

                string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "youremaildevoloper@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
                string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = @"C:\yourpath\privatekey.p12";
                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate =
                new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret",
                      System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

Comment: Hello Jipo,
Thanks for being so helpful & patient. I will try this Server Authentication method you have described and let you know how I get on with it.